# git, create a branch to manage partial files

Tags: git, github

I have a github repository for auto build docker image.

```
https://github.com/trumanz/dockerBuild
```

Docker hub could auto build on specific branch.
My repository contains a Dockerfile on each directory.

So I want to create a branch, e.g  branch name "rabbitmq", then I can see only directory rabbitmq.

I tried to create a branch rabbitmq, and delete other directors, but when I merge it to master, the master will delete other directors.

Comment: In the merge commit, you can tell git what you want to commit (and you can exclude the file deletions). But why merge back to master at all? Wouldn't you want to develop on master and then merge back into the branch?

Comment: my git repo seems like "directoryA   directoryB";  I want use brach  A work on direcotryA,  and brach B work on direcotryB, then I can see all on work master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I want to create a branch, e.g  branch name "rabbitmq", then I can see only directory rabbitmq.

You should use submodule to do it.
Submodule is a standalone folder (repository) inside git repository. The submodule is a folder but the folder contains another git repostry

Its exactly what you asked

[image]